# Search up text from a file and take whole line using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way using batch to take a specific chunk of text, search for it in the txt file, and if it finds that text it will take the line that it is on and save the whole line as a variable?

For Example:

```
@echo off
Rem THIS IS THE BATCH FILE!
set /p op="Enter Text To Search>"
if %op%==%op% goto Search

:Search
Rem Search in text file: information.txt
Rem Find Chunk of text and line its on
Rem And after its found save the whole line as a variable!

Echo %Whole_Line%
pause
exit
```

And An example text file:

```
Set dt=2015-10-20 Set Tm=18:05:47.47 Set Ipw=%ipwan% set loc=%location% Set Img=%ImgName%.bmp
Set dt=2015-10-21 Set Tm=06:20:10.28 Set Ipw=%ipwan% set loc=%location% Set Img=%ImgName%.bmp
Set dt=2012-01-09 Set Tm=8:09:26.31 Set Ipw=%ipwan% set loc=%location% Set Img=%ImgName%.bmp
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple FOR /F with FINDSTR

First EDIT: add logic for not finding a line.

Second EDIT: Script now sets a new environmental variable for each line it finds.

```
set "whole_line1="
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G IN ('findstr /C:"%op%" information.txt ^|FINDSTR /N /C:"%op%"') do set "whole_line%%~G=%%~H"
IF NOT DEFINED whole_line1 GOTO error
```

Comment: Thanks! if it cant find your text anywhere in the file can you make it run a command? Eg. Goto Error

Comment: Thanks Again. This should be my last question now. if it finds more than one line with the chunk of text in it, can it set each different line as a variable? Sorry i didn't mention this earlier.

Comment: @Jakers326, in the future please think about what you need to have accomplished before you post your question.  Less time wasted.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry. Thanks So Much!